# Como realizar cálculos em cima de um arquivo CSV com Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Estou aprendendo alguns comandos para análise de dados extraídos de um arquivo CSV e travei na seguinte situação:

Quero usar como base esse CSV para realizar a média da sala:

```
Nome;P1;P2;P3
Maria;8;7;10
Julia;9.5;10;7
Ailton;7;8;10
Leo;4;5;3
```

Até agora tenho isso, o qual sei ser o início:

```
import csv
with open('notas.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    lista = []
    for row in csv:
        lista.append(row)
```

Como faço para ter como resultado a média da sala por prova e após isso a geral com todas as provas?

Apenas preciso que no final seja impresso:

```
Média P1: X, média P2: Y, média P3: Z. Média final: A
```

Com **X** sendo a média entre todas P1, **Y** a média entre todas P2, **Z** a média entre todas as P3 e A a média entre todas as notas.

Caso se adicionem mais provas ou pessoas, a conta deve continuar sendo feita com o mesmo código.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e detalhe o problema e o código para entendermos quais os dados de entrada e saída, para que possamos te ajudar, não somos um fórum de debates, não tem como ficarmos chutando resposta, dê os parametros minimos. Obrigado!

Comment: Publicação editada.

Comment: Obrigado julia, e qual a "saida" de dados esperada baseado no CSV de exemplo na sua pergunta?

Comment: Editada novamente.

Comment: Tá, posta os resultados como deveriam ser, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você começou bem, mas eu tenho dois comentários sobre o seu código:

1. Ele não descarta a linha de cabeçalho presente no CSV, então o conteúdo `Nome;P1;P2;P3` seria interpretado como notas de um aluno;
2. Ao ler do arquivo, você terá as notas como *string*, mas para fazer operações matemáticas, precisará delas como números.

Assim, corrigindo esses dois itens, ficaria como:

```
import csv

turma = []

with open('data.csv') as stream:
    reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)  # Descarta o cabeçalho
    for line in reader:
        nome, *notas = line
        turma.append([float(nota) for nota in notas])
```

Fazendo isso, o objeto `turma` ficaria:

```
[
    [8.0, 7.0, 10.0], 
    [9.5, 10.0, 7.0], 
    [7.0, 8.0, 10.0], 
    [4.0, 5.0, 3.0]
]
```

A quantidade de alunos será a quantidade de registros em `turma`:

```
quantidade_alunos = len(turma)
```

A quantidade de provas será a quantidade de notas que cada aluno tem:

```
quantidade_provas = len(turma[0])
```

Para calcular a média de cada aluno, basta somar suas notas e dividir pelo número de provas:

```
media_aluno_0 = sum(turma[0]) / quantidade_provas
```

Para calcular a média da turma em uma prova, basta somar as notas e dividir pelo número de alunos:

```
media_prova_1 = sum(provas[0] for provas in turma) / quantidade_alunos
```

E, finalmente, para calcular a média da turma, basta somar todas as notas e dividir pelo número de notas, que é o produto da quantidade de alunos pela quantidade de provas:

```
quantidade_notas = quantidade_alunos * quantidade_provas
media_total = sum(sum(provas) for provas in turma) / quantidade_notas
```

---

Para a versão 2.7 do Python, não é possível fazer:

```
nome, *notas = line
```

Para obter o mesmo resultado, podemos definir uma função auxiliar:

```
def unpacking(a, *b): return a, b
```

E utilizá-la no lugar:

```
nome, notas = unpacking(*line)
```

Assim, da mesma forma, `notas` receberá a lista de notas.

Comment: Tentei o mesmo, mas estou tendo o erro "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" em "nome, *notas = line"

Comment: @JuliaRicci É, acabei colocando como Python 3. Precisa mesmo fazer na 2.7? Por quê?

Comment: Infelizmente precisa, pois é o único aceito na programação de programas internos na minha empresa. Seria possível adaptar para o Python 2.7?

Comment: @JuliaRicci coloquei ao final da resposta